# Control recursive method depth - get all sub folders

Tags: c#, recursion, .net-3.5

I'm traveling through some shares to get information/permissions .. etc
I'm using recursive to travel through all sub shares. it works fine however, the user should be able to limit the sub shares level to specific number which is a parameter in the application?

```
private static INodeCollection NodesLookUp(string path)
    {
        var shareCollectionNode = new ShareCollection(path);
        // Do somethings

       foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(shareCollectionNode.FullPath))
        {
            shareCollectionNode.AddNode(NodesLookUp(directory));

        }
        return shareCollectionNode;
    }
```

this code will go all way to the lowest level, how can i stop it in specific level? for example get all shares until 2 levels only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using a global variable to control the level, pass the `maxLevel` and decrement with each recursive call.

```
private static INodeCollection NodesLookUp(string path, int maxLevel)
{
    var shareCollectionNode = new ShareCollection(path);
    if (maxLevel > 0)
    {
        foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(shareCollectionNode.FullPath))
        {
            shareCollectionNode.AddNode(NodesLookup(directory, maxLevel-1));
        }
    }
    return shareCollectionNode;
}
```

Comment: +1 for short solution, but it's not like it's global, it's at the same level, as `static` method is declared.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: No, not really *global*, but it's external mutable state. Next best thing to a global variable, and limits the method to single-threaded use.

Comment: it's not mutable, at least in my example. Anyway, accessing only local to method data is always a better thing.

Comment: While short and effective, your method *does not* actually have any information about the level it operates on (it's just how close its level is to the max/bottom level). Just a thought.

Comment: @JimMischel: Seems can be write in a extension method with *this* be `INodeCollection`.

Comment: @KenKin: No, because we're not passing an `INodeCollection` to the method.

Comment: @JimMischel: Ah .., I know. Since I see that `ShareCollection` take a *path*, so I'm thinkg maybe `(new ShareCollection(path)).NodesLookup(...)`, just be an idea.

Answer (score 6):

How about passing `level` variable and increasing it after each level of recursion call? This will allow you to control what are the current recursion level or how many levels left. Don't forget to check for null.

```
private const int maxDepth = 2;

private static INodeCollection NodesLookUp(string path, int level)
{
   if(level >= maxDepth)
        return null;

   var shareCollectionNode = new ShareCollection(path);
   // Do somethings

   foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(shareCollectionNode.FullPath))
   {
       var nodes = NodesLookUp(directory, level + 1);

       if(nodes != null)
            shareCollectionNode.AddNode(nodes);

   }
   return shareCollectionNode;
}
```

Initial level can be zero-indexed, like

```
NodesLookUp("some path", 0);
```

Comment: Please change your maxDepth to be static. Otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: Private const - nicely played, sir! However, what if two different callers want to use this method for different depths? They are limited to this fixed value which extends the whole class and is used only in one context.

Comment: *Besides, that max level - as the OP states - should be a parameter (this requires some clarification, btw), not a compiled value.

Comment: @PiotrJustyna `if two different callers want to use this method for different depths` - just pass another value into `level` parameter. Sure, I agree that solution presented by Jim is shorter and more flexible. I've used `private const` just because I assume no one can use it outside that class and that class shouldn't change it due to a reasons, discussed in comments section in Jim's answer.

Comment: Oh yeah, it was just a thought :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
    private static INodeCollection NodesLookUp(string path, Int32 currentLevel, Int32 maxLevel)
    {
        if (currentLevel > maxLevel)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var shareCollectionNode = new ShareCollection(path);
        // Do somethings

        foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(shareCollectionNode.FullPath))
        {
            INodeCollection foundCollection = NodesLookUp(directory, currentLevel + 1, maxLevel)

            if(foundCollection != null)
            {                
                shareCollectionNode.AddNode();
            }
        }

        return shareCollectionNode;
    }
```

In this case you don't have to worry about the state of your private fields being modified each time the method runs. And, as far as the rest of your code is thread-safe, it will be thread-safe.

Comment: Won't this end up adding `null` entries to the collection?

Comment: @JimMischel No, why would it?